# how do I find string in directory file, and splitting into a new line?

Tags: sed, grep

I have a directory with 100+ files

sample file:

```
{"title","really long file here that"]},{"title","that is really a long line all together"]}
```

I would like to grep all the files in the directory for the text **{"title** and split it into a new line every time the text is found. How do I do that with grep/sed? or if there is any other better solution

output file should be:

```
{"title","really long file here that"]},
{"title","that is really a long line all together"]}
```

Comment: If this is supposed to be JSON please post valid JSON.

Comment: this is a json, I don't think that is important, the text is grouped into multiple long lines, new lines should begin at "title".

Comment: I suggest to replace all `,{"title"` with `,\n{"title"` with GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

If `GNU sed` is available, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in dir/*; do
    grep -q '{"title' "$f" && sed -Ei 's/,(\{"title)/,\n\1/g' "$f"
done
```

where `dir` is your directory of the files.

Here is an alternative without GNU sed:

```
#!/bin/bash

nl=$'\n'    # newline character
for f in dir/*; do
    grep -q '{"title' "$f" && sed -Ei 's/,(\{"title)/,\'"$nl"'\1/g' "$f"
done
```